# How can i print custom message on bootstrap methods

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

When I click on a button "Click Me" it change into "Loading" and after loading it becomes "Loading Complete".

How can I change this text "Loading" to "Saving" and "Loading Complete" to "Saved Successfully"?

You can view what I want from [this](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=string-button-method) link

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$("#myButton").click(function(){
    $(this).button('loading').delay(1000).queue(function() {
        $(this).button('complete');
        $(this).dequeue();
    });        
});
});
</script>

<div class="bs-example">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"
    id="myButton" data-complete-text="Loading Completed"
    autocomplete="off">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the bottom of the code you have the following:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="myButton" data-complete-text="Loading Completed" autocomplete="off">Click Me</button>
```

There is a property named `data-complete-text="Loading Completed"`
Here you can change the text when the button is loaded.

To add text while loading. Add the following property:

```
data-loading-text="loading-text.."
```

The product looks like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="myButton" data-loading-text="YOUR LOADING TEXT" data-complete-text="YOUR LOADED TEXT" autocomplete="off">Click Me</button>
```